# Resample/aggregate NetCDF file to resolution of second NetCDF file

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to resample or aggregate a NetCDF file with about 10 km x 10 km resolution to exactly the same resolution as a second NetCDF file with approx. 30 km x 30 km resolution. The NetCDF files should afterwards not only have the same spatial resolution, but their grid cells should also exactly overlie.

I know of the gdalwarp which can be run in the terminal but there one can only specify the output resolution with [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] - setting georeferenced extents of the output file to be created - or [-tr xres yres] - setting output file resolution (in target georeferenced units). I, however, need to make sure the grids of the two NetCDF files exactly align in the end and would, therefore, like to give the raster object that already has the final resolution as the output extent argument. 
Is there any way to do that?

With rasters, I can do this in R with the raster package simply using resample(x, y, method = "..") where 
x is the Raster* object to be resampled and
y the Raster* object with parameters that x should be resampled to.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In R,  I suggest you use `projectRaster` from `raster` or `st_warp` from `stars`. Outside of R, `gdalwarp` is a good coiche, if you carefully choose your settings (this will also help you understand what those values *mean*). Otherwise, using `cdo` and specifically the `remap*` operators will do exactly what you need, you just need to specify the remapping method, the input file, the output file and the reference grid (or file). See the manual [here](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf).